# How to get a strongly typed linq query of a data table and database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, strong-typing

I have seen other solution that resemble my problem very closely but somehow it doesn't work for me.

I have a linq query to a db with a join to a datatable which is not strongly typed.
I need a strongly typed result to return for a view.

My try looks like this

```
var query = (from t in queryAllTasks
             join tL in table.AsEnumerable() on t.TaskId equals tL.Field<int>("TaskId")
             select new { t.TaskId, Kasten = tL.Field<int>("Box") }).AsEnumerable();
```

Here is the datatable if its of interest:

```
//Create new DataTable.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        //Declare DataColumn and DataRow variables
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;

        //Create ne DataColumn
        //set DataType
        //ColumnName
        //add to Datatable
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "TaskId";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        //Dritte Spalte
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "Box";
        table.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: Your selected anonymous type is strongly typed, so what's the question?

Comment: If there are no obvious mistakes, then maybe the problem is more on the asp.net issue than my c# code. Because it complains about not being ienumerable.

Comment: For what? Your query is already an `IEnumerable<of an anonymous type>` even without the redundant `AsEnumerable`. Maybe you need something that is not an anonymous type.

Comment: yes, thats also an interesting direction, I will look into that.

Comment: When you say *Strongly Typed* do you mean a [Typed DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use named custom type, instead of anonymous type. If you are using `new { ... }` construct, then you are creating anonymous types, which aren't usually passed out or into methods. If you do pass anonymous type out of the method, you need to cast it to object or make formal parameters as dynamic and then access its fields, which I don't really recommend, especially in the view. I suggest to change your query to:

```
var query = from t in queryAllTasks
             join tL in table.AsEnumerable() on t.TaskId equals tL.Field<int>("TaskId")
             select new MyModel{ TaskId =  t.TaskId, Kasten = tL.Field<int>("Box") };
```

Where you `MyModel` is defined as

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public int Kasten { get; set; }
}
```

As the result, you will have named `IEnumerable<MyModel>` in the view with known inner structure, that you can use at your view. Hope this will solve your issue, which as far as I understood, is the lack of ability to access query results from a view.

Comment: ok I tried that now. In the debugger it complains about the table not just being made of purely primitive types. But its made of two int32 columns, it doesn't get more primitive! I am getting ready to use something different than datatable, if necessary. Any advice there ?

Comment: Well, it's hard to recommend something, because I'm not in your context and don't know anything about your requirements and environment. Could you please edit your question with the details of how exactly do you use query in the view? Maybe you need to execute query bring  it to memory by adding extra ToList() before passing query into view?